# Custom iAd in app

Tags: ios, iad

I would like to add a custom iAd to my app. I don't want to release it to any other apps. I just want it to be in my app, no one else's. I also want to have other people's ads, too.

Is this possible?

Comment: that does not make sense! you want something to be advertised just in your app? Why? Or am I understanding you wrong? You want some advertisement you create and distribute through iAd to be shown only in some specific apps!? Then there would be no need for iAd, since you can just display the ad yourself in the app.

Comment: @luk2302 I still want other advertisements, but instead in my application, also have my own ad.

Comment: Then you could just not display iAd and instead display your own ad from time to time, i don´t see the need to use iAd for that purpose, that would just cost you money.

Comment: @luk2302 Okay. I think I need to think this through some more, but could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at two possibilities here:

First option: you pay money to distribute your advertisement through iAd and maybe somehow limit it to be displayed only in your app. (would not suggest)

**OR** you could (and should) just hide the iAd from time to time and display your own advertisement instead. That way you don´t need to rely on Apple to show your ad and don´t have to pay anything. This way you may also be able to show your ad if the iAd is unavailable due to flight mode or something similar, IF the ad is locally available in your app.

You may also have a look at alternatives for iAd, maybe they suit your requirements better.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Detailed answers are the best. I can accept it in 1 minute.